# '{Read the txt file and filter the records with date < date, > date and in between dates}'

Tags: shell, awk, sed

sample.txt

```
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  5 14:30 file4.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  6 14:31 file6.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  7 12:15 file9.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  8 12:15 file8.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  9 14:03 file7.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul 10 14:03 file66.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul 11 11:41 file5.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul 12 11:42 file4.txt
drwxr-xr-x    2 atom atom     1024 Jul 13 09:12 file3.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom     4401 Jul 14 09:46 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom     4401 Jul 14 09:46 file1.txt
```

I would like to identify the records based on date.

for example if i want to identify last 8 days files means form Jul 14  to Jul 7

expected output:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  7 12:15 file9.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  8 12:15 file8.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul  9 14:03 file7.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul 10 14:03 file66.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul 11 11:41 file5.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom        0 Jul 12 11:42 file4.txt
drwxr-xr-x    2 atom atom     1024 Jul 13 09:12 file3.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom     4401 Jul 14 09:46 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 atom atom     4401 Jul 14 09:46 file1.txt
```

Comment: why did you not even try to make your question mor readable?

Comment: could you please check now

Comment: could you use the '{}', after selecting the appropriate text in your question?

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understand, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If `sample.txt` contains the output of `ls` (as it appears to) and you're trying to parse it then see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Don't post-filter.  For this task, it would be more appropriate to pre-filter and only generate data for those files with the appropriate mtime. It is much easier to compare mtimes by using a timestamp than to try to do the natural language processing required to match names like "Jul" and "Aug".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -l  | awk '/Jul/ && 0+$7>=8'
```

`ls -l` for the long output

Then `awk` will find lines containing `Jul` and (&&) the seventh paramater ($7) needs to be larger or equal to 8.

The `0+` is there to convert the alphanumeric piece to numeric, because it's no use comparing a string to an integer.

Comment: That would fail if a file had a June timestamp but was named `Julius.txt`, for example. Also note the usual warnings: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: Thanks you@Luuk,@john, @Ed Morton

Comment: Tried with awk in generic manner and another problem is it is not working for 6 moths old date list 
 `awk -vDate=`date +'%b %e'` -vDate2=`date +'%b %e' -d '-7 day'` ' { if ($6 " " $7 > Date2 && $6 " " $7 < Date) print $0}'`

Comment: You have 2 different links to https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs in comments so that shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: try using `ls -l --full-time` which makes checking the date much easier.